# Pourquoi « nec plus ultra » est la forme reprise/retenue de cette locution latine courante ?

Tags: anglais, latin, comparaison-de-langues, emprunts, morphologie

La locution provenant du latin scolaire moderne [*nec plus ultra*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nec_plus_ultra), « relativement courante » pour « l'idée intensive de la qualité insurpassable », est attestée vers 1714 (DHLF ; TLFi : [1728](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/nec%20plus%20ultra)). « Les expressions anglaises *non plus ultra* (1608) et [*ne plus ultra*](https://archive.org/details/oed6barch/page/n925/mode/1up) (1638), ainsi que l'expression française [*non plus ultra*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A7N0125) (1638), sont reprises à d'autres formes latines. » (DHLF). La locution fait partie d'un ensemble de [locutions latines courantes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3799).

Y a-t-il une raison particulière qui explique le succès de la forme avec *nec* en français ? Les autres locutions latines courantes sont-elles généralement d'une forme particulière (ou possèdent-elles une autre caractéristique) qui leur serait commune, ou tendent-elles à le devenir ?

Answer (score 4):

Je me risque à tenter une hypothèse : les formes en concurrence pouvaient prêter à confusion à l'écrit car « non plus » et « ne plus » existent en français avec des sens différents (*neither, no longer, no more...*) alors « *nec* » indique clairement qu'on a affaire à une locution latine et entraîne aussi une prononciation spécifique.

Comment: Merci, donc un argument de cohérence phonétique et sémantique ? Finalement il y a peu de ces locutions où une confusion en trompe-l’œil serait possible. Disons _Michel dit non liquet_, pas particulièrement utile. Spontanément, avec _de facto_, _de jure_ et _de visu_, penses-tu que la deuxième va rester plus longtemps prononcée particulièrement pour éviter une situation similaire à ce que ton hypothèse décrit ?

Comment: J'ai en effet du mal à imaginer qu'on puisse prononcer *de jure* avec un e final muet. Il faudrait peut être une réforme qui propose *de juré*. Le *de* est déjà francisé dans les trois cas et on est de toute façon avec /də ʒyʁe/ bien loin du /de jure/ latin ("dé youré").

Comment: *Dé jouré* ou *dé juré* ?

Comment: Celui-là je le prononce comme dé (dé youré). Mais j'ai eu une introduction à la langue sur quelques années, mais on nous refusait la versification, on n'était pas assez bon pour daigner essayer de traduire en latin haahahé.